# Form rendering in object's method

Tags: php, forms, templates

I am very new to PHP MVC Method and recently i encountered a problem of displaying a form from my View.php

the code goes here (Controller_Shipping.php)

```
<?php
include 'View_Shipping.php';
 class Controller_Shipping{

    public $view;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->view = new View_Shipping();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->view->showForm();
    }
 }
 ?>
```

the view file is as simple as below (View_Shipping.php)

```
<?php
class View_Shipping{

    public function showForm(){
?>      
 <form method="post">
    <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
   <p>
  <label for="name"> Title Name </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="Title" autofocus>
 </p>
   <p>
<button type = "submit"> Save </button> 

  </p>
</form>
<?php
} // end of showForm()
}
 ?>
```

it displays nothing at all when i load it via "localhost/Controller_Shipping.php". but i create another very very simple php like "localhost/testing.php" which only contains

```
<?php

include "Controller_Shipping.php";

$testing = new View_Shipping();

echo $testing->showForm();


?>
```

It works. comes to controller it fails.. does it relate to assigning the Controller class a new object?

Comment: add index to your constructor? Doesn't look like you're calling index anywhere so it's not going to do anything.

Comment: Thanks bryan but i call it in the constructor and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not echoing out the contents (like you are in your test). 
Do either

```
 public function index(){
       echo $this->view->showForm();
    }
```

or

```
 public function showForm(){

 echo '<form method="post">
    <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
   <p>
  <label for="name"> Title Name </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="Title" autofocus>
 </p>
   <p>
<button type = "submit"> Save </button> 

  </p>
</form>';

} // end of showForm()
```

Frankly, I would not make View_Shipping a class. Just make it a standard php file

Comment: thanks for your help. but it does not work. tried both of them but displays the same result.

Comment: Well then you will need to post more code from your controller, because if you are echoing it fine from the test, then it should work fine from index. Something else is causing the problem. Do you have output buffering on that you arent displaying?